# What's the difference between Element setProperty and TitanVertex addProperty in Blueprints?

Tags: graph-databases, titan, tinkerpop

What is the difference between the Blueprints methods `vertex.addProperty(key, value);` implemented in TitanVertex and `vertex.setProperty(key, value);` in Element?

If there is a difference, how can I translate `addProperty` into `setProperty`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Titan has the notion of [multi-properties](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Type-Definition-Overview#wiki-single-and-multi-value-keys) which is not a part of the Blueprints API.  A multi-property "allows a list of values on this property key for each vertex. This is useful when a property key is multi-valued, like "email" for example, since a user can have multiple email addresses".

If you use multi-properties then you can only set them via `TitanVertex.addProperty`.  You can't set them via any Blueprints methods.